# How to parse json array into controller in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, arrays

I am working on ASP.NET MVC 4.0 application.

I am sending my form's value to controller like this in Kendo Window refresh option :-

```
var frm = $("#formUpdate");

var productWindow = $("#ProductWindow").data("kendoWindow");
productWindow .refresh({            
       url: "../../Product/UpdateProduct",
       data: { model: JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray())}
});
```

And below is the string that i am getting on controller :-

```
[{"name":"DefaultAddressNumber","value":""},{"name":"Id2","value":"tax id 1"},   {"name":"Id2","value":"tax id 2"},{"name":"Id","value":"5"},{"name":"ProductTaxes","value":""},{"name":"ProdcutId","value":"20"},{"name":"InsuranceId","value":""},{"name":"OrgAddr1","value":""},{"name":"OrgAddr2","value":""},{"name":"OrgAddr3","value":""},{"name":"Name","value":"Amit Kumar"},{"name":"Description","value":"Description"},{"name":"SelectedProductSubTypeId","value":""},{"name":"IsEmailFinalizedProduct","value":"False"}]
```

And i want to do deserialize that string again into form of array or object or something in which i can read/get it easily.

And for that i have used below code :-

```
var productString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductViewModel>(str);
```

But i am getting the below error while i am using this :

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'ProductRepository.ViewModel.ProductViewModel' because the type
>   requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize
>   correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a
>   type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList)
>   like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
>   JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array.
>
> Path '', line 1, position 1.
>
> > Can any one help me out on this,means how can i parse this string ?

Comment: try `var productString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<ProductViewModel>>(str);`

Answer (score 0):

use `JSON.stringify` to outer side like..

```
var frm = $("#formUpdate");

var productWindow = $("#ProductWindow").data("kendoWindow");
productWindow .refresh({            
       url: "../../Product/UpdateProduct",
       data: JSON.stringify({ model: frm.serializeArray()})
});
```